# Applying discount on a certain price

Tags: python

```
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8  # The pay rate after 20% discount

    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        # Run validations for the received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        # Assign to self objects
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

        def calculate_total_price(self):
            return self.price * self.quantity

        def apply_discount(self):
            self.price = self.price * Item.pay_rate

item1 = Item("Phone", 100, 1)
item1.apply_discount()
print(item1.price)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riyam\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\OOT.py", line 20, in <module>
    item1.apply_discount()
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'apply_discount
```

They are showing that `item1.apply_discount()` has no attribute.
What changes should be made?

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with your indentation such that the apply_discount() function is limited in scope to __init__()

What you need is:

```
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        # Run validations for the received arguments
        assert price >= 0, f"Price {price} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        assert quantity >= 0, f"Quantity {quantity} is not greater than or equal to zero!"
        # Assign to self objects
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def calculate_total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * Item.pay_rate

item1 = Item("Phone", 100, 1)
item1.apply_discount()
print(item1.price)
```